# smile haarcascade

Tags: iphone, opencv, sensors, emotion

I have tried to integrate smile haarcascade (smileD_haarcascade_v0.05) in OpenCV but it only detect mouth portion how it will will detect whether person is smiling or not ?

Comment: @Black: Can you please suggest how can i detect any person is smiling or not ?

Comment: Do you mean that this cascade issues lots of false positives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please review the KB below, focus on the training part.

http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

Comment: Its a huge content. Okay I will take a look with full concentration. Is it really gonna help me ? I have to develop iphone application. There are lots of command in this article not relevant to Objective C.

Comment: @Tariq well I assume according to your question that you tested with https://github.com/hromi/SMILEsmileD/raw/master/smileD/smiled_05.xml and you did not get the required results.. so you can review the KB and run the training and generate another one which will be more how should I put it.. answering your demands..:-) have lovely day.